# Is it possible to change the Tabbar Item text/Icon on the fly while app is running?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to change the Tabbar Item text/icon on the fly while app is running?

For example the name of the item on the tabbar is Item1. I want to programmatically change it to 'ItemX' while the app is being used.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[how to set individual tabbaritem icons in uitabbarcontroller in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978116/how-to-set-individual-tabbaritem-icons-in-uitabbarcontroller-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 2):

Where you want to change the Tabbar Item text/icon?In the view controller itself?You can change Tabbar Item text/icon in view controller as follows:

```
self.title = @"ItemX";

self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ItemX"];
```